# Regular expression to fix invalid JSON

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I'm making an API call to a service, but it's returning invalid JSON. The photo_url field doesn't have the url encapsulated in quotes. I have it as a String, and was trying to write a regex to add quotes around the url. I'm doing this all in Javascript, using Titanium.

This is the code I have now:

```
var response = '[{"friend_request":{"about_me":"","friend_id":"11043271728","gender":"M","display_name":"foo","age":21,"photo_url":http:\/\/s.foo.com\/img\/nopic\/MB_90x90_male.gif,"hometown":""},"friend_request":{"hometown":"","display_name":"bar","gender":"M","age":"","friend_id":"11040542298","about_me":"","photo_url":http:\/\/s.foo.com\/img\/nopic\/MB_90x90_male.gif}}]';
var pattern = /http.*(,|\}|\s)/i;
var flip = target.match(pattern);
var foo  = target.replace(flip, "\"" + flip + "\"");
console.log(foo);
```

Here's the JSON in human-readable form:

```
[
  {
    "friend_request": {
      "about_me": "",
      "friend_id": "11043271728",
      "gender": "M",
      "display_name": "foo",
      "age": 21,
      "photo_url": http:\/\/s.foo.com\/img\/nopic\/MB_90x90_male.gif,
      "hometown": ""
    },
    "friend_request": {
      "hometown": "",
      "display_name": "bar",
      "gender": "M",
      "age": "",
      "friend_id": "11040542298",
      "about_me": "",
      "photo_url": http:\/\/s.foo.com\/img\/nopic\/MB_90x90_male.gif
    }
  }
]
```

Right now, it's finding the beginning of the pattern, but going on even further. I believe it has something to do with commas. I know there are multiple pattern matches that should happen, but for now, I was just trying to get one to work. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Trying to fix broken JSON with regular expressions is like trying to estinguish fire by throwing a bottle full of gasoline in it. In both cases you end up with the same result: a huge explosion.

Comment: You can test your regex's here, it works really well: http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Did you send the service provider a bug report?

Comment: The service provider's a client, and I needed this for a temporary solution. I am drafting an email now though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var response = '[{"friend_request":{"about_me":"","friend_id":"11043271728","gender":"M","display_name":"foo","age":21,"photo_url":http:\/\/s.foo.com\/img\/nopic\/MB_90x90_male.gif,"hometown":""},"friend_request":{"hometown":"","display_name":"bar","gender":"M","age":"","friend_id":"11040542298","about_me":"","photo_url":http:\/\/s.foo.com\/img\/nopic\/MB_90x90_male.gif}}]';

var str = response.replace( /("photo_url":)([^,}]+)([,\}])/g, '$1"$2"$3' )
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems like an incredibly elegant solution.