# Fetch specific values from string

Tags: javascript

I have following string

```
var a = "{gallery: 'gal', smallimage: '/uploads/photo/image/3256/big_1303-1.jpg', largeimage: '/uploads/photo/image/3256/zoom_1303-1.jpg'}";
```

What is the best way to fetch largeimage value which is "/uploads/photo/image/3256/zoom_1303-1.jpg" 
Let me tell you guyz currently i am using this.(which is very basic)

```
var a = "{gallery: 'gal', smallimage: '/uploads/photo/image/3256/big_1303-1.jpg', largeimage: '/uploads/photo/image/3256/zoom_1303-1.jpg'}";
var b = a.split('largeimage:')[1].split("'")[1];
```

Comment: @E_net4 are you just commenting to make him feel bad, or do you want to be helpful at all?

Comment: George - it's not working i tried it

Comment: This ain't no `JSON`.

Comment: @error-404 I suggested it before actually looking at the JSON, which isn't valid.

Comment: it isn't valid json, is there any alternate way ?

Comment: Does it have to be a string? Remove the "" and you have a valid object notation

Comment: @Joe I apologize for that interpretation. I seriously started imagining the question asking for a few steps further, such as retrieving the image data. And only a few moments after, I noticed the lack of quotes in the attributes.

Comment: @johan : it has to be string, i am fetching this string from somewhere, dont have control over that

Comment: Just posted a working object parser for you. It may not work with way-complicated objects, but should handle your sample case

Comment: Did you see my solution...?

Answer (score 0):

Have only this idea.

```
var a = "{gallery: 'gal', smallimage: '/uploads/photo/image/3256/big_1303-1.jpg', largeimage: '/uploads/photo/image/3256/zoom_1303-1.jpg'}";

var b = a.split(',');

var c = b[2].split("'");

var img = c[1];

console.log(img););     // "/uploads/photo/image/3256/zoom_1303-1.jpg"
```

[**JSFIDDLE.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hkwxk7ux/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choice here:

1. Make your string a valid JSON - to do this you will need to wrap gallery, largeimage, smallimage with apostrophe.
   so it would look like this:

   ```
   var validJSONstring = '{"gallery": "gal", "smallimage": "/uploads/photo/image/3256/big_1303-1.jpg", "largeimage": "/uploads/photo/image/3256/zoom_1303-1.jpg"}';

   var validJSONObject = JSON.parse(validJSONstring);
   console.log(validJSONObject.largeimage);
   ```

Then you have to parse it to JSON and get the property name.

2. Split the string where separator sign is "," comma, loop through results and split each result when separator sign is ":" and check for the property you are looking for.

Comment: i cant change the string, no control over it

Comment: What you posted is not valid JSON either.

Comment: @Felix, you are correct, I have changed my answer and now the it's a valid JSON. the change I made was replacing the out apostrophe with Quote

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough implementation of parsing a valid JS object. It doesn't support nested objects, but for the sample string it will work correctly.

```
function parseObject(objString) {
    var obj = {},
        parts,
        part,
        splitPart;

    // Remove leading and trailing {}s
    objString = objString.trim().replace(/^{|}$/g, '');
    parts = objString.split(','); // split properties into an array

    for (part in parts) {
        splitPart = parts[part].split(':'); // split key/value

        // .join for values containing ':', then the regex removes leading and trailing quotes and spaces
        obj[ splitPart[0] ] = splitPart.slice(1).join(':').replace(/^\s*['|"]\s*|\s*['|"]\s*$/g, '');
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var a = "{gallery: 'gal', smallimage: '/uploads/photo/image/3256/big_1303-1.jpg', largeimage: '/uploads/photo/image/3256/zoom_1303-1.jpg'}";

var jsontemp = a.replace((/([\w]+)(:)/g), "\"$1\"$2");
var correctjson = jsontemp.replace((/'/g), "\"");
var obj = JSON.parse(correctjson);
var c = obj.largeimage;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hev64veL/)

For turning into valid json, I used the solution from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24462870/888177

Comment: `a` is a string. It does not have a `.largeImage` property

Comment: Working on it, hang on!