# Formatted string to js array

Tags: javascript, arrays, model-view-controller

I'm using an MVC app and my controller gets a string like this from mongodb:

```
str = "[{ title: 'My title', items: [{ name: 'item1', link: '#' }, { name: 'item2', link: '#' }] }]"
```

And I'm trying to use it in the view as a **js Array**, but I can't find any way to convert it.

Note that the array will have some sub arrays as items and some sub sub arrays, and so on.

Any help? Maybe I have to build the array inside my business layer instead of returning a string?

Comment: MVC is not an app. It's arcitectural pattern. Are you using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: can you change the format of that string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing nothing else about the structure of your app, the easy way to convert that string into an object is using `eval()`.

```
var object = eval("[{ title: 'My title', items: [{ name: 'item1', link: '#' }, { name: 'item2', link: '#' }] }]");
```

That said, NEVER use `eval()` on a string that you do not absolutely trust. It is very easily abused and exploited.

Comment: Thanks @ntdb, that did the trick. I will anyways try to get the object in some other way from my app, just taking your warning not to abuse from eval().

Answer (score 4):

the solution is JSON:
have a look at the docs:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

And here is what you'd need to do:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

This will give you a Javascript-Object (JSON=JavaScriptObjectNotation) which you then can access like that:

```
var firstTitle = obj[0].title;  // 'My title'
var itemsArrayOfFirstObject = obj[0].items;  // an Array of items
var linkOfForstItemInFirstObject = obj[0].items[0].link; // '#'
```

**EDIT:**

I oversaw that in your example the string is not in valid JSON-format

Comment: Unfortunately JSON.parse doesn't work here because the string is not valid JSON (note the lack of quotes around the keys).

Comment: @ntdb so probably you should modify something at the back-end to provide valid JSON for later parsing. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462658/convert-invalid-json-string-to-json

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will change the string to valid JSON, which is then returned as an object using `JSON.parse()`:

```js
function parse(str) {
  var t= '',
      special= '[]{} :,',
      qt;

  str= str.split('');

  for(var i = 0 ; i < str.length ; i++) {
    if((qt=str[i])==="'" || qt==='"') {
      do {
        t+= str[i++].replace("'",'"');
      } while(i < str.length && str[i]!==qt);
      t+= qt.replace("'",'"');
    }
    else if(special.indexOf(str[i])===-1) {
      t+= '"';
      do {
        t+= str[i++];
      } while(i < str.length && special.indexOf(str[i])==-1)
      t+= '"';
      i--;
    }
    else {
      t+= str[i];
    }
  }
  return JSON.parse(t);
} //parse

obj = parse("[{ title: 'My title', items: [{ name: 'item1', link: '#' }, { name: 'item2', link: '#' }] }]");
console.log(obj[0].items[1].name); //item2
```

I threw this together quickly, so I may be overlooking something.  But it works with your example string.