# Get variable data from response

Tags: json

Hello From API I am getting following response.

```
{{status:'ok', tracking_no:'4444',label_pdf:'base64 pdf'}}
```

I validate online above json but it is not valid json.

But API returning me above json so I have to extract tracking_no from api so how I will ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert invalid JSON string to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462658/convert-invalid-json-string-to-json)

Comment: Fix your API to return valid JSON (with keys and string values in double quotes, and no double `{{ }}`). Otherwise, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462658/convert-invalid-json-string-to-json.