# Replace ' character by " using regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I get a string: "{ a: '123', b: '234'}", I want to make it to be "{ "a": "123", "b": "234" }" by using regex expression. Could anyone explain/guide me how do I do this? The following is my trial.

```
str.replace(/[']/,'"').replace(/(['"])?([a-z0-9A-Z_\-]+)(['"])?\s*:/g, '"$2":')
```

Comment: did you miss a colon after "b" or you want this to be parsed?

Comment: Yes, I actually want this to be parsed. Thank you for your remind, I will edit my question

Comment: *"...using regex expression."* Why? Would other options work if available?

Comment: And where are you getting this string from? Is the source trusted?

Comment: No. It is a mistype only.

Comment: @Tellui right. Then just use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @Aron: Again: The input is invalid JSON. The `a` and `b` would have to be in `"`, and the values would have to be in `"`, not `'`.

Comment: @Tellui: Again: Is the source trusted?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. However, I am not clear, do you mean that the ' cannot be replaced to be " using the regular expression and JSON parse together, as I just want to get the json as { "a": "123", "b": "234"} only.

Comment: @Tellui: I understand your end goal. I'm asking you where the string comes from and whether you can trust that source.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think I find my problem now. You are right, in fact I think I am getting strings from the html template using the angular directive. However, it failed in this case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert invalid JSON string to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462658/convert-invalid-json-string-to-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var yourjson = "{ a: '123', b: '234'}";
var jsontemp = yourjson.replace((/([\w]+)(:)/g), "\"$1\"$2");
var correctjson = jsontemp.replace((/'/g), "\"");
alert(correctjson);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwdzv8yp/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `JSON.parse`. That's what it's made for.

Comment: But `"{ a: '123', b: '234'}"` is no valid JSON

Comment: I actually want the JSON to BE {"a":, "123", "b": "234"}. I don't understand why the topic is down voted.

Comment: @Tellui you've just put a comma after the `a:`. Is that intentional? Because of your (maybe) typos it's difficult to understand what you're after: a parser for faulty JSON or just a regular JSON parser?

Comment: Okay. Let me make these all more clear :) by editing.